# Trying to do a selection.replace with an xlUp

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, vba

So I'm trying to to a variable range find and replace where I fill in blank spaces with "blank" for a row insertion where I drag down a row. All's I need is help fixing my xlUp so that it works with the selection.replace.

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()
Dim LR As Long
Set LR = Range("A2:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
Range(LR).Select
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="Blank", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

I forgot to add the error as well, its "Compile Error: Object Required"
I'm working a lot with excel in my internship this summer, and I'm looking forward to becoming more knowledgeable about this stuff. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub ReplaceBlanks()

Dim LR As Range

Set LR = Range("A2:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)

LR.Replace What:="", Replacement:="Blank", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```